# Можно ли сделать некоторые пункты ListView нефокусабельными?

Tags: getview, android, listview

Нужно, чтобы при пролистывании ListView с помощью клавиш вверх и вниз некоторые пункты(в зависимости от содержимого) не выбирались и не выделялись, а в целом список вел себя как обычно. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то в адаптере *ListView* переопределяем *areAllItemsEnabled* (возвращая, соответственно, *false*), а также, *isEnabled*, где уже возвращаем нужное значение для конкретного элемента.

Comment: Спасибо! Работает!

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в адаптере ListView в методе getView установить этому самому возвращаемому View флажок setFocusable(false)